# Jquery accordian-like content switching

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a very basic accordion-like (http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) content display system. i'm new at this and also stubborn, so I didn't use the one provided.
here is the code:

```
        $(".listitem").click(function(){
            $("#info"+$(this).attr('id')).slideToggle("fast");
        });

<h3 class="listitem" id="1">title 1</h3>
<div id="info1">blah blah blah 1</div>

<h3 class="listitem" id="2">title 2</h3>
<div id="info2">blah blah blah 2</div>
```

all the list items  have the id of a number 1-6 or whatever, and the hidden content has the id of "info" + the corresponding number. My question is how could I make it such that when a new item is clicked, it closes the previous one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of which one's open.

```
(function() {
    var open = -1;
    $(".listitem").click(function() {
        var id = this.getAttribute("data-page");
        if( id != open) {
            $("#info"+id+", #info"+open).slideToggle("fast");
            open = id;
        }
    });
})();

<h3 class="listitem" data-page="1">title 1</h3>
<div id="info1">blah blah blah 1</div>

<h3 class="listitem" data-page="2">title 2</h3>
<div id="info2">blah blah blah 2</div>
```

Note that I have replaced your `id` attributes with `data-page`, since in HTML4 it is not valid to have an ID starting with a number and it's inappropriate use of ID anyway. Additionally, I replaced the `$(this).attr(...)` with its vanilla JS equivalent for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".listitem").click(function(){
         var content=$(this).next();
        $('.listitem+div:visible').slideToggle("fast",function(){
                content.slideToggle("fast");
              });
        });
```

The trick here is using the `:visible` selector in jQuery; which selects only visible elements that match the previous selector, once all of the visible content is hidden, the content that was just clicked on will open

Also `.listitem+div` means select the div that comes right after all elements with the listitem class